# Navigation bar animation. WHY. WEIRD

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationbar

When I run my application, you can see the navigation bar animates in very quickly, it seems like I only catch the end. The animation also seems like it slides down from the top. I have written no code for it to do this! That's why it's weird!

Here's the weirder thing. In the info.plist if I set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to "NO" this does NOT happen. It only happens when I set it to "YES"!

I want "View controller-based status bar appearance" to be set to "YES" because I want to be able to turn it off on specific view controllers using:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Please help!

Comment: So where do you have that code, when does it animate and what options do you have set in the storyboard?

Comment: Are you calling -setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate after you have applied your changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to `View controller-based status bar appearance` in plist file, it means, that you will determine logic of status bar inside your app.

Do you assume that `UIStatusBar` and `UINavigationBar` are the same?
Definetly not.

So you function:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

is hiding status bar (20px bar with battery, clocks and mobile cell).

If you want to change it's animation you should use:

```
override func preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation() -> UIStatusBarAnimation {
    return .None
}
```

If you want to hide `UINavigationBar` in some view controller, you should call inside view controller:

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```